# Highcharts - position column chart from the top

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts column chart trying to show the completion of something with one column and the drop-off in an adjacent column along the x-axis.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2vXqZ/

```
     series: [
        {
            data: [300, 150, 85, 75, 35],
            pointWidth: 60,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: 90,
                color: 'white',
                align: 'right',
                x: -10,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '25px',
                }
            },
            stack: 'completion'
        },
        {
            data: [150, 65, 10, 40],
            color: '#ff8546',
            pointWidth: 20,
            groupPadding: -0.2,
            stack: 'drop-off'
        },
        {
            data: [150, 85, 75, 35],
            color: 'transparent',
            pointWidth: 20,
            groupPadding: -0.2,
            stack: 'drop-off',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    ]
```

The blue column is the raw value, whereas the orange column between each blue one is the drop-off (the difference from the previous column). Right now, I have this setup with sort of a hack by stacking two columns (stack: 'drop-off') and having the bottom part be transparent.

Is there any cleaner solution for this? Any way I can have the orange column simply be positioned from the top instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always set your drop-off series as a `columnrange` type.

```
     series: [
        {
            data: [300, 150, 85, 75, 35],
            pointWidth: 60,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: 90,
                color: 'white',
                align: 'right',
                inside: true,
                x:-10,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '25px',
                }
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'columnrange',
            data: [[0.5,150,300],[1.5,85,150],[2.5,75,85],[3.5,35,75]],
            color: '#ff8546',
            pointWidth: 20,
            groupPadding: -0.2
        }
    ]
```

See update fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2vXqZ/1/).